# Why doesn’t height: 0 hide my padded <div>, even with box-sizing: border-box?

Tags: css

I’ve got a `<div>` with padding. I‘ve set it to `height: 0`, and given it `overflow: hidden` and `box-sizing: border-box`.

```css
div {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 40px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello!</div>
```

As I understand, this should make the `<div>` disappear.

However, it’s still visible (in Chrome 31 and Firefox 25 on my Mac). The `height` declaration doesn’t appear to be applying to the padding, despite the `box-sizing` declaration.

Is this expected behaviour? If so, why? [The MDN page on `box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) doesn’t seem to mention this issue.

Nor, as far as I can tell, does [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0) — it reads to me like both width and height should include padding when `box-sizing: border-box` (or indeed `padding-box`) are set.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use this kind of div in real world, you should make extra wrapper DIV inside this and move padding to it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The exact definition of `border-box` is:

> That is, any padding or border specified on the element is laid out and drawn inside this specified width and height. The content width and height are calculated by subtracting the border and padding widths of the respective sides from the specified ‘width’ and ‘height’ properties.

So you can modify the height and width properties, but `padding` and `border` never change.

> As the content width and height cannot be negative ([CSS21], section 10.2), this computation is floored at 0.

Then, if `height` is 0, you can't make the padding be inside, because that implies the height will be negative.

Answer (score 19):

The declaration of `height: 0;` is applied. If you leave it at `height: auto;`, you would see a 20px difference (the height of the line with "Hello!"), making it a total 100px high. With height set to zero, it's only 80px high: `padding-top + padding-bottom = 80px`

So the answer is: **Yes, it's expected behavior.**

You could set width and height to any value between `0` and `80px` (if you have 40px of padding) and still get the same dimensions.

Update: As Hardy mentioned, using an additional wrapper div gets around this issue.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FA29u/12/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="div-1">
    <div class="div-2">
        Hello!
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.div-1 {
    padding: 40px;
    
    /* This is not visible! */
    border: 1px solid tomato;
}
.div-2 {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: So, you’re saying that `box-sizing` doesn’t have any effect on top and bottom padding? Only left and right?

Comment: You can't set `width: 0;` along with `padding: 40px;` either and making it invisible. Width width and height set to zero, you'll still have a 80px x 80px big box.

Comment: Aha, I see. So, with `box-sizing: border-box`, the browser will set the size of the *content area* so that the overall width or height of the element is as close to the supplied width/height dimension as possible. But the content area can’t have a negative dimension, so the padding will always be visible. Got it, thank you.

Comment: The definition is a bit squishy when it comes to this point, I understand your confusion.

Comment: It is a wee bit unintuitive, I agree. Once I read the spec description abit more slowly, with more of an open mind, I got it.

Comment: The definition makes sense, but this unfortunately has the effect of not being able to set the resulting box to zero, if it has padding, no matter what.

Comment: Another workaround would to add `::before` and `::after` elements with `display: block; height: 40px;` to create the same effect as the padding would create, while retaining the ability to set the height to values less than the combined vertical "padding".

Comment: The question by the OP wasn't my exact question, but I saw that you had `overflow:hidden` and that fixed my problem. thanks!

Comment: ` border: 1px solid dashed;` this line is just wrong, what if you change it to `border: 1px solid black`. What is `solid dashed` ?

Comment: @windmaomao yeah, the idea is right, but CSS is completely upside down. This works: https://jsfiddle.net/914mfpxw