# box oversizing when using heigh in % and border in px

Tags: html, css

Good evening,

I have a question that has been bothering me for a while. I have 2 divs, 1 is menu wrapper and the other one is main content div. they have the following CSS code:

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

#menu{
height:6%;
border-bottom: 4px solid #3D3D3D;
}

#mainContentDiv{
height:93%;
padding: 0.5%;
}
```

With the following code I get an overflow (scroll bar), which I would like to avoid. After a little Googling I've found that `box-sizing: content-box;` is supposed to fix it, but apparently it doesn't (or I'm doing something wrong).

Is there any way to fix this, without having any overflow or fixing the overflow with CSS?

Comment: It´s content-box per default. Try 'border-box'.

Answer (score 0):

Without the rest of the page I cant say for sure but try the overflow: property in CSS;
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

CSS example:

```
div
{
width:150px;
height:150px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: this is not the solution I'm looking for as it will not remove the overflow the browser window.

Comment: provide a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) and we'll take the time to look through it, only with the current information its hard to judge exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have this situation : http://jsfiddle.net/rHBq2/2/.

Then you have scroll beacuse total `height` is calculated this way:

```
6% of #menu 
+
4px border of #menu
+
93% of #mainContentDiv
+
1% padding of #mainContentDiv
= 
100% + 4px
```

Then you have extra space in addition to the 100%. You can solve that with `box-sizing`:

```
#menu{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:6%;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3D3D3D;
}
#mainContentDiv{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:94%;
  padding: 0.5%;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/RDExD/

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, thank you. but could you please explain better how box-sizing works? as w3schools' version is a bit confusing.

Comment: @user3111896 look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827367/why-doesnt-height0-hide-my-padded-div-even-with-box-sizingborder-box/20827604#20827604 i explain the definition